# Generate permutations of specific length with repetition in R?

Tags: r, permutation

I have a list of words and I need to generate all the permutations with repetition. The length of permutation must be specified. The words list is quite big(i.e.  30 words) so the function I needs to be efficient too.. 
  Example:

```
wordsList = c("alice", "moon", "walks", "mars", "sings", "guitar", "bravo")
```

I need to generate all the permutations given that each permutation must have exactly 3 words.  That would be `["alice", "moon", "walks"]`, `["alice", "walks", "moon"]`, `["moon", "alice", "walks"]`  etc

Comment: My computer hangs when I provide a big list(i.e. 3000 words list , which needs to generate combinations of 15 words). Any idea how can I distribute or make it less RAM dependent ?

Comment: Generating that many permutations isn't feasible. That is over `10^52` total permutations (`prod(3000:2986) = 1.38546e+52`).

Comment: You have `["alice", "moon", "walks"]` two time in a row.... Did you mean `["alice", "moon", "walks"]`, `["walks", "alice", "moon"]`, `["moon", "alice", "walks"]`?

Comment: @JosephWood there was a duplicate indeed. I've fixed it now. Concerning the number of combinations I believe I need reconsider it. However the least I could do is combinations of 11 words from a list of  2100 which I believe is doable using some cloud hardware. The main issue is that I don't know how to distribute/parallelize the load.

Comment: It looks like I get some errors like ``cannot allocate vector of size 483342.8 Gb`` 480TB of RAM is really insane... and I'm pretty sure I didn't hit the last iteration

Comment: Did you read the last bit of my answer? I give options for working around this. Other than generating a subset, I don’t really see any other options.

Comment: Thanks.. I will look around for available options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several packages that will produce exactly what you need.  Let's start with the classic `gtools`. Also, from the looks of the example provided by the OP, we are looking for permutations without repetition, not combinations with repetition.

```
wordsList <- c("alice", "moon", "walks", "mars", "sings", "guitar", "bravo")

library(gtools)
attempt1 <- permutations(length(wordsList), 3, wordsList)
head(attempt1)
        [,1]    [,2]     [,3]    
[1,] "alice" "bravo"  "guitar"
[2,] "alice" "bravo"  "mars"  
[3,] "alice" "bravo"  "moon"  
[4,] "alice" "bravo"  "sings" 
[5,] "alice" "bravo"  "walks" 
[6,] "alice" "guitar" "bravo"
```

Then there is `iterpc`.

```
library(iterpc)
attempt2 <- getall(iterpc(length(wordsList), 3, labels = wordsList, ordered = TRUE))
head(attempt2)
        [,1]    [,2]    [,3]    
[1,] "alice" "moon"  "walks" 
[2,] "alice" "moon"  "mars"  
[3,] "alice" "moon"  "sings" 
[4,] "alice" "moon"  "guitar"
[5,] "alice" "moon"  "bravo" 
[6,] "alice" "walks" "moon"
```

And finally, `RcppAlgos` (which I am the author of)

```
library(RcppAlgos)
attempt3 <- permuteGeneral(wordsList, 3)
head(attempt3)
        [,1]     [,2]     [,3]    
[1,] "alice"  "bravo"  "guitar"
[2,] "bravo"  "alice"  "guitar"
[3,] "guitar" "alice"  "bravo" 
[4,] "alice"  "guitar" "bravo" 
[5,] "bravo"  "guitar" "alice" 
[6,] "guitar" "bravo"  "alice"
```

They are all fairly efficient and produce similar outcomes (different orderings)

```
identical(attempt1[do.call(order,as.data.frame(attempt1)),],
          attempt3[do.call(order,as.data.frame(attempt3)),])
[1] TRUE

identical(attempt1[do.call(order,as.data.frame(attempt1)),],
          attempt2[do.call(order,as.data.frame(attempt2)),])
[1] TRUE
```

If you really want permutations with repetition, each function provides an argument for carrying out that function.

Since the OP is working with a `wordsList` with more than 3000 words and is looking for all permutations chosen 15 at a time, the aforementioned methods will fail.  There are some alternatives, from `iterpc` as well as `RcppAlgos`.

With `iterpc` you can use the function `getnext` and produce successive permutations.  I doubt you will be able to produce them all in a reasonable amount of time or store them in one location (i.e. assuming each cell occupies 8 bytes, `10^52 * 15 * 8/(2^80) > 10^29 YB` yes... those are [yobibytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix#yobi)... interpretation: "*a lot of data*").

With `RcppAlgos` you can utilize the `rowCap` argument to output a specific number of permutations up to `2^31 - 1`. E.g.:

```
permuteGeneral(wordsList, 3, upper = 5)
        [,1]     [,2]     [,3]    
[1,] "alice"  "bravo"  "guitar"
[2,] "bravo"  "alice"  "guitar"
[3,] "guitar" "alice"  "bravo" 
[4,] "alice"  "guitar" "bravo" 
[5,] "bravo"  "guitar" "alice"
```

Comment: There is also `permn` from the `combinat` package. There are probably other packages that provide this functionality that I'm leaving off (unintentionally).

Comment: It looks like that OP wants *combinations* with *repetition*. `iterpc` is the only package that I am aware of which have the ability to generate combinations with replacement (suppose it is what OP wants).

Comment: @RandyLai , both `gtools` and `RcppAlgos`, are capable of generating combinations with repetition. For `gtools`,  setting the fifth argument `repeats.allowed` of the `combination` function toggles this feature and for `RcppAlgos`, the third argument `repetition` does the same. See the documentation [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gtools/versions/3.5.0/topics/combinations) and [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RcppAlgos/versions/0.2.1/topics/comboGeneral).

Comment: @RandyLai , also, if you look at the OP’s requested output, they are clearly confused about what a combination is vs a permutation. OP says _”I need to generate all the combinations....”_ and then proceeds to list out 3 identical combinations. As you know order doesn’t matter w/ combinations but does w/ permutations. Anywho, I really `iterpc`.

Comment: @RandyLai, I meant "I really **like** `iterpc`".

Comment: We are right about gtools. I was thinking something else: `itepc` is the only package that I know to be capable of drawing combinations from a multi set. Thank for your information though.

Comment: "We are" -> "You are"

Answer (score 0):

You could use the function `combn` from the `utils` package.

```
wordsList = c("alice", "moon", "walks", "mars", "sings", "guitar", "bravo")
combn(wordsList, 3)
```

Which gives a long output I don't want to reproduce here. You can also have the input be a factor, which might help with the speed.

Comment: There is no need to call `library(utils)` as it is a preloaded base package.

Answer (score 0):

To truly generate *combinations* with *repetitions*, Joseph Wood's solutions were about permutations without repetitions. (Edit: though OP wrote combination with repetition, he may mean permutation!? See comments)

```
library(iterpc)
wordsList = c("alice", "moon", "walks", "mars", "sings", "guitar", "bravo")
getall(iterpc(length(wordsList), 3, labels = wordsList, replace = TRUE))
#>       [,1]     [,2]     [,3]    
#>  [1,] "alice"  "alice"  "alice" 
#>  [2,] "alice"  "alice"  "moon"  
#>  [3,] "alice"  "alice"  "walks" 
#>  [4,] "alice"  "alice"  "mars"  
#>  [5,] "alice"  "alice"  "sings" 
#>  [6,] "alice"  "alice"  "guitar"
#>  [7,] "alice"  "alice"  "bravo" 
#>  [8,] "alice"  "moon"   "moon"  
#>  [9,] "alice"  "moon"   "walks" 
..
..
```

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking for even though the title says  _"...combinations with repetition..."_.  See the comments to the OP's question and also examine his requested output (those are permutations, not combinations). Also, maybe it has been a while since you used `gtools`, but it is completely capable of generating combinations with repetition (see [here](https://gist.github.com/randy3k/10015496)).

Comment: Ai, you are right about gtools, I have missed that. I guess only OP knows what he wants though. But you are absolutely right that his examples look more like permutations than combinations.